# Our Client wants to capture login/sign up information on their website into Marketing cloud.

Tags: marketing-cloud

So I provided them with a code using DEManager to implement in their website.

When the code is implemented on my Client's website, it is throwing an error

Failed to load "https://cl.s7.exct.net/DEManager.aspx:**No "Access Control Allow Origin"** header is present on the requested resource.

The error is appearing in the URL in the form action :

Could someone help me understand why we are getting this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more of your code - without further context, your question is unlikely to be answered and could wind up being closed.